# exporting animation in .AVI

Tags: graphics, export, animation

i have a problem with exporting an animation as a video; i can't get the animation to only go in one direction it awlays goes forward and backwards.
AnimatioDirection does nothing.
i can't remove the animator too.
I should also convert it into a .MP4 file later.
thanks in advance, i know I am a newbie.
code below

```
a = Animate[
Show[{curv, 
Plot[{-uexact[x, t]}, {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 9}], 
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, 
Point[{-16.89587 + 16 (t + 1), 8}]}], 
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Orange, 
Point[{-4.346573590279973 + 4 (t + 1), r}]}]}], {t, -1, 1}, 
AnimationDirection -> Forward, AppearanceElements -> None]
Export["2-sol.avi", a, "AVI", "AnimationDirection" -> Forward]
```

Comment: Use `Table` (with `t` as index) instead of `Animate` to make list of graphics frames. Then export that list into .AVI. Both problems - repetition and removal of control - will be solved. Next time post full code please - or just a minimal example.

Comment: ... see first example in docs on [AVI](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/AVI.html)